# (C# / Window) How to know all request URLs?

Tags: c#, window, request

I have been developing a project that uses PHP and C#.

We're writing a C# App and installing it on some computers, and a PHP website that manages these computers.

When something is changed on Server. C# App will connect to server and get new updated information that relates to current computer, to do this job C# App requests to server each ten seconds.

My question is "Can I see all requests by on the current computer?" The computer is installed by window 7 or window 8.

Note: I can see all requests by looking in file "access_log" on server. But I want to know whether I can do it in the sending computer or not? Thank you so much.

Or I can log in C# when doing a request to Server.

(Sorry about my English)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fiddler to monitor all traffic leaving and returning to your computer over port 80.

Also, you can add logging to your C# program to log anything you want to a file, and then review the log later.

By default, the requests you make in C# won't be logged to a system event log or anything like that.